# How to make request to linked container from frontend js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm building application using docker-compose.

One docker container is a rails api only app. Second is node.js app with angular.

What I need is to make POST and GET requests to rails container in order to get data from it to my Angular app.

docker-compose.yml

```
rails_server:
  build: ./rails_server
nodejs_server:
  build: ./nodejs_server
  ports:
    - "80:8080"
  links:
    - rails_server
```

I tried to get access to rails container using ENV variables that docker compose provide for me. Like `MICROSERVICEAPP_RAILS_SERVER_1_PORT_3000_TCP_ADDR`, `MICROSERVICEAPP_RAILS_SERVER_1_PORT_3000_TCP_PORT`. There env vars return `172.17.0.2` and `3000` accordingly.
But the point is browser client don't have access to internal docker private network. So I'm unable to make requests to my rails app. I think I can send requests back to node js and then to rails but it feels wrong.

How should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the right approach was to use proxy server on my nodejs container.

For example. My Express js is looking for requests to /api endpoint  and just proxying them to my RoR container.

Like:

```
var config = {
  api_uri: process.env.MICROSERVICESCHAT_API_1_PORT_3000_TCP || "http://localhost:3000"
}

var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

app.all('/api/*', function (req, res) {
  req.url = req.url.replace(/\/api/, '');
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: config.api_uri });
});
```

You can look at it more closely in a sample application here https://github.com/gabyshev/microservices_chat

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote it seems that you need to access `rails_server` from the browser which implies that `rails_server` should be accessible from the outside. Similarly as you published ports for `nodejs_server` container, publish ports for the `rails_server` container:

```
rails_server:
  build: ./rails_server
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
nodejs_server:
  build: ./nodejs_server
  ports:
    - "80:8080"
  links:
    - rails_server
```

This way in the browser if you request `http://host_ip_address:8080/` it will be redirected to your `rails_server` container